# Is there any high level Audio Queue Record Service Library for iOS?

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, xcode, macos

I'm trying to develop an application which about VOIP,

is there any high level audio queue service library for iOS ?

because I'm not very good at for working on extension filename ".mm",

using an open source would be a better option.

or someone could give me some hints for how to fetch the buffer from AudioQueueBufferRef ?

the ideal way is like a delegate :

```
- (void)audioRecorderDidReceivedBuffer:(Buffer) {
    do something for other operations
}
```

---

- **Update**
  I found an article which about [Using RemoteIO audio unit](http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/)

  maybe the input callback is what I need.

> Overvier
>
> 1. Identify the audio component (kAudioUnitType_Output/ kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO/ kAudioUnitManufacturerApple)
> 2. Use AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &descriptionOfAudioComponent) to obtain the AudioComponent, which is like the factory with which you
>      obtain the audio unit
> 3. Use AudioComponentInstanceNew(ourComponent, &audioUnit) to make an instance of the audio unit
> 4. Enable IO for recording and possibly playback with AudioUnitSetProperty
> 5. Describe the audio format in an AudioStreamBasicDescription structure, and apply the format using AudioUnitSetProperty
> 6. Provide a callback for recording, and possibly playback, again using AudioUnitSetProperty
> 7. Allocate some buffers
> 8. Initialise the audio unit
> 9. Start the audio unit
> 10. Rejoice

```
// Enable IO for recording
UInt32 flag = 1;
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                              kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                              kInputBus,
                              &flag, 
                              sizeof(flag));



// Set input callback
AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
callbackStruct.inputProc = recordingCallback;
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = self;
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                              kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
                              kInputBus, 
                              &callbackStruct, 
                              sizeof(callbackStruct));



//recordingCallback
static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                              AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                              const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                              UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                              UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                              AudioBufferList *ioData) {

// TODO: Use inRefCon to access our interface object to do stuff
// Then, use inNumberFrames to figure out how much data is available, and make
// that much space available in buffers in an AudioBufferList.

AudioBufferList *bufferList; // <- Fill this up with buffers (you will want to malloc it, as it's a dynamic-length list)

// Then:
// Obtain recorded samples

OSStatus status;

status = AudioUnitRender([audioInterface audioUnit], 
                         ioActionFlags, 
                         inTimeStamp, 
                         inBusNumber, 
                         inNumberFrames, 
                         bufferList);
checkStatus(status);

// Now, we have the samples we just read sitting in buffers in bufferList
DoStuffWithTheRecordedAudio(bufferList);
return noErr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the method that how to fetch Audio Buffer from recording

( reference from: http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/ )

```
static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                                  UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                                  UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                                  AudioBufferList *ioData) {

    // TODO: Use inRefCon to access our interface object to do stuff
    // Then, use inNumberFrames to figure out how much data is available, and make
    // that much space available in buffers in an AudioBufferList.

    AudioBufferList *bufferList; // <- Fill this up with buffers (you will want to malloc it, as it's a dynamic-length list)

    // Then:
    // Obtain recorded samples

    OSStatus status;

    status = AudioUnitRender([audioInterface audioUnit], 
                             ioActionFlags, 
                             inTimeStamp, 
                             inBusNumber, 
                             inNumberFrames, 
                             bufferList);
    checkStatus(status);

    // Now, we have the samples we just read sitting in buffers in bufferList
    DoStuffWithTheRecordedAudio(bufferList);
    return noErr;
}
```